# Finding logic for this output

Tags: c

Explain how this output comes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x,y,z;
  x = y = z = -1;
  z = ++x && ++y && ++z;
  printf("%d %d %d", x, y ,z);
  return 0;
}
```

I thought x,y,z all values will be 0 but the actual output is x=0,y=-1,z=0.

Answer (score 2):

You have a incorrect declaration to start with, the last variable in the declaration should have been `z` instead of `x` back again (corrected since the last edit)

As for the result, you would see an output `0 -1 0`, because after the first pre-increment, the value of `x` becomes `0` and the evaluation short-circuits ( operand right to `&&` is not evaluated) as `0 && ++y` producing integer `0`  and pre-increment on `y` never happening at all. The expression now becomes `0 && (++z)` which would short-circuit again to produce `0`

The result of the final expression `z` when printed with `%d` specifier becomes `0`.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect, it should have been "declaration" instead of  "initialization". But anyway I corrected the OP's typo and you can remove that sentence. On the other hand I didn't get your explanation about `z` being 0

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Thanks, did write it in haste, now corrected

Comment: This answer uses the jargon “short-circuits” without defining it and does not explicitly state there is a rule that, if the left operand of `&&` is zero, the right operand is not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that are involved here: Operator associativity, and [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (please see the link for a description of what it is and what it does).

Due to the associativity of the `&&` operator, the expression `++x && ++y && ++z` is equal to `(++x && ++y) && ++z`.

If we do the sub-expression `++x && ++y` then the result is `false`. What happens is that `++x` results in `0`, so we have `0 && ++y`. And in C zero is the same as boolean `false`, and due to the short-circuit evaluation `++y` never happens. The value of `y` stays at `-1`.

So with the result of the first sub-expression, we have `false && ++z`. Again due to short-circuit evaluation `++z` never happens, and the result is again `false`.

So the result of `++x && ++y && ++z` is `false`, which is then assigned to `z`. And in the assignment the boolean `false` is implicitly converted to the integer value `0`. Which is the printed value of `z`.

Comment: This answer uses the jargon “short-circuit” without defining it and does not explicitly state there is a rule that, if the left operand of `&&` is zero, the right operand is not evaluated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's why I have the link to Wikipedia.

Comment: This answer does not explicitly state there is a rule that, if the left operand of `&&` is zero, the right operand is not evaluated. If fails to explain the most critical reason the expression produces results in question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why should I duplicate the effort of the Wikipedia article?

Comment: The result of `++x && ++y` is 0, not `false`. In C++, the result of `&&` is a Boolean `false` or `true`. In C, the result is an `int` 0 or 1. Also, it is imprecise at best to say that “zero is the same as boolean `false`”, and it is unnecessary in this answer as there is no `false` or other `_Bool` type involved.

Comment: The answer to the question should be in the answer. Links are for supplemental information, not for the core part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-differences-between-bitwise-and-logical-and-operators-in-cc/) I can read

> The `‘&&’` operator doesn’t evaluate second operand if `first operand becomes zero`.

```
z = ++x && ++y && ++z = ((++x && ++y) && ++z)
```

> **Inner parenthesis** `(++x && ++y)`

- `++x = -1 + 1 = 0` second operand `++y`  ***is not evaluated***, `y = -1, z = -1`

> **Outer parenthesis**

```
((++x && ++y) && ++z) = (0 && ++z)
```

Again `++z` ***is not evaluated*** `z` remains `-1`

- `++x && ++y && ++z  = 0` and `x = 0, y = -1, z = -1`
- Then you overwrite the value of `z` by  assigning `++x && ++y && ++z = 0`  to `z`
- so the old value of `z` namely `-1` is replaced by `++x && ++y && ++z` namely  `0`

Finally

```
x = 0, y = -1, z = 0
```

Comment: In C, unlike C++, the result of `&&` is 0 or 1, not `false` or `true`.

Comment: In the bitwise version, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, because the value of C is modified twice without sequencing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What do you mean by the  `the value of C is modified twice without sequencing`?

Comment: Typo, the value of `z` is modified twice without sequencing.

Comment: Per C 2018 6.5 2, “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…” The `++` operator has the side effect of incrementing its operand, and the assignment operator `=` has the side effect of storing a value in its left operand. With the expression `z = ++x & ++y & ++z;`, these side effects are not sequenced (specified by the C standard to be in a particular order), so the rule in 6.5 2 says the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil agree since **all operands are evaluated** **_once at a time_**

Comment: @EricPostpischil You mean `++x` `++y` `++z` happen but `++x & ++y & ++z` never happen?

Comment: In `++z`, the `++` operator has two effects, a main effect and a side effect. The main effect is to provide the incremented value of `z` for the expression evaluation. The side effect is to assign the incremented value to `z`. The main effect happens during evaluation of the expression. When the side effect occurs is not fully specified by the C standard. The actual store to `z` may occur before, during, or after evaluation of the entire expression `z = ++x & ++y & ++z;`.…

Comment: Similarly, in `z = …`, the `=` operator has two effects. The main effect is to provide the value that is assigned to `z`. (For example, in `a = z = 3;`, `z = 3` is an expression that has value 3, which is assigned to `a`.) The side effect is to store a value into `z`. The C standard does not fully specify when this side effect occurs. So `z = ++x & ++y & ++z;` has two side effects that both affect `z` but that are not sequenced relative to each other. That violates the rule in 6.5 2, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard.